# rviz fixed frame no tf data

Tags: ros, rviz, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 14.04 with Indigo destop full installed.

```
roscore &

rosrun rviz rviz
```

then in Rviz,

```
Global Status: Warn
Fixed Frame. No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

also, Fixed frame: there is nothing but map.

Your informative advice are welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229017/rviz-fixed-frame-no-tf-data/) by [epoc88](https://answers.ros.org/users/26262/epoc88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have a mobile robot: There is no localization running which procides the transform from `map` to `odom` (or what it is called in your robot).

Run `rosrun tf view_frames` to get a PDF with the tf tree as well as the publishers.

---

Answer was: You need to start more than just `rviz`. `rviz` is just for visualization, but you need other nodes that publish what you want to visualize....

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [epoc88](https://answers.ros.org/users/26262/epoc88/) on 2016-03-14**:
inside the generated  frames.pdf

no tf data recieved

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-14**:
alright, let's take a step back...

Please **edit** your question with all commands that you actually start, as well as the launch files.
If you only start `roscore` and `rviz`, then you have nothing that publishes any data, not `tf`, not `map`, not `Laserscans`...

**Comment by [epoc88](https://answers.ros.org/users/26262/epoc88/) on 2016-03-14**:
ok..that answers the question..thanks! the tutorial at my hand is not clear.
I thought this was due to environment problem.

i am newbie just started ROS 1 days ago, with brand new ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo installed.